# (Xamarin.Forms IOS) PDF image not displaying

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have a cross platform application created in Xamrin Forms. The Application works perfectly in **Android** and **UWP**. But when loading in **IOS** the icons are not visible.
For example

```
<Image >
      <Image.Source>
          <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="FileImageSource">
              <On Platform="Android" Value="login_icon" />
              <On Platform="UWP" Value="Images/login_icon.png" />
              <On Platform="iOS" Value="login_icon" />
          </OnPlatform>
       </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

I have added all my images in the **PDF format** in the **Assest Catalog**. The size of the images are also correct. But for some reason the icons are not displaying.
However if i add these images into **Resources as .png** they appear. The offical document says this approch is deprecated.

**EDIT:**
Everything looks good in the simulator but when i test using a real device, these icons are not visible.

Comment: In doc [Displaying an Image in Xamarin IOS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/displaying-an-image), note section [Using vector images in asset catalogs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/displaying-an-image?tabs=windows#using-vector-images-in-asset-catalogs): *"a PDF formatted **vector** image"*. Does the PDF contain **vectors** (**NOT a bitmap composed of pixels**)? If you have a (jpg/png) **bitmap**, the recommended approach is to create an **Image Set**, to which you add different resolutions of the image.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I have a svg image may be i will try to convert that into PDF and try again.

Comment: Does that work?

Comment: @AdrainZhu-MSFT I have to create a vector image in the proper size first . I will update as soon as i test it

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Still no luck however all the Icons are visible in the Simulator. when i test using a device these icons are not visible

Comment: @AdrainZhu-MSFT no its not working in device

Comment: Can you show us the code you set the icon and the icon file?

Comment: @AdrainZhu-MSFT Amm binding my icons exactly the way i have given in the Question. login_icon is in PDF format added in the Asset Catalog as ImageSet

Comment: Try reinstall the app in your device.

Comment: @AdrainZhu-MSFT tried that a lot of time. there are no changes.

Comment: How about create a new sample app in ios to test if the icon display or replace the pdf with png to see how it wroks?

Comment: 1) You picked emulator device same as the real device? Same OS version? 2) *"I have a svg image"* - How was the SVG file created? 3) If you can't get PDF to work, you can always use the alternative solution I mention in my first comment: Make an **Image Set**. This means providing the image at the different required resolutions. Its more effort, but it is easier to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CutomRenderer to create a custom webview to display pdf file.

code like:

```
    public class CustomWebView : WebView
    {
        public static readonly BindableProperty UriProperty = BindableProperty.Create (propertyName:"Uri",
                returnType:typeof(string),
                declaringType:typeof(CustomWebView),
                defaultValue:default(string));
    
        public string Uri {
            get { return (string)GetValue (UriProperty); }
            set { SetValue (UriProperty, value); }
        }
    }
```

In IOS:

```
   [assembly: ExportRenderer (typeof(CustomWebView), typeof(CustomWebViewRenderer))]
    namespace DisplayPDF.iOS
    {
        public class CustomWebViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<CustomWebView, UIWebView>
        {
            protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<CustomWebView> e)
            {
                base.OnElementChanged (e);
    
                if (Control == null) {
                    SetNativeControl (new UIWebView ());
                }
                if (e.OldElement != null) {
                    // Cleanup
                }
                if (e.NewElement != null) {
                    var customWebView = Element as CustomWebView;
                    string fileName = Path.Combine (NSBundle.MainBundle.BundlePath, string.Format ("Content/{0}", WebUtility.UrlEncode (customWebView.Uri)));
                    Control.LoadRequest (new NSUrlRequest (new NSUrl (fileName, false)));
                    Control.ScalesPageToFit = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the document about customrenderer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/introduction

Comment: I don't want to show the PDF. My Icons are in PDF format, these icons are not visible.